# How to change the default annotation of A,B,C to the title of addColumn in Annotation chart of google api chart?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

Google annotation chart shows default annotation like A,B,C,.. But I'd like to change this annotation to the title values in data.addColumn like below:

[image]

[google annotation chart api](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart)

Comment: not possible out of the box, you can modify manually after the chart has been created. unfortunately, those particular buttons are added after the chart's `'ready'` event has fired, so you'll have to use another event or a `MutationObserver`...

Comment: Then can I put in the box? That is 'G' is replaced with 'Gallantors'.